# How to use mock in function run in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-multiprocessing

In my code, I use multiprocessing.Pool to run some code concurrently. Simplified code looks somewhat like this:

```
    class Wrapper():
        session: Session       


        def __init__(self):
            self.session = requests.Session()
            # Session initialization


        def upload_documents(docs):
            with Pool(4) as pool:
                upload_file = partial(self.upload_document)
                pool.starmap(upload_file, documents)

                summary = create_summary(documents)

            self.upload_document(summary)


        def upload_document(doc):
            self.post(doc)


        def post(data):
            self.session.post(self.url, data, other_params)
```

So basically sending documents via HTTP is parallelized. Now I want to test this code, and can't do it. This is my test:

```
    @patch.object(Session, 'post')
    def test_study_upload(self, post_mock):
        response_mock = Mock()
        post_mock.return_value = response_mock
        response_mock.ok = True

        with Wrapper() as wrapper:
            wrapper.upload_documents(documents)

        mc = post_mock.mock_calls
```

And in debug I can check the mock calls. There is one that looks valid, and it's the one uploading the summary, and a bunch of calls like `call.json()`, `call.__len__()`, `call.__str__()` etc.

There are no calls uploading documents. When I set breakpoint in `upload_document` method, I can see it is called once for each document, it works as expected. However, I can't test it, because I can't verify this behavior by mock. I assume it's because there are many processes calling on the same mock, but still - how can I solve this?

I use Python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take here is to keep your test as granular as possible and mock out other calls. In this case you'd want to mock your `Pool` object and verify that it's calling what you're expecting, not actually rely on it to spin up child processes during your test. Here's what I'm thinking:

```
@patch('yourmodule.Pool')
def test_study_upload(self, mock_pool_init):
    mock_pool_instance = mock_pool_init.return_value.__enter__.return_value

    with Wrapper() as wrapper:
        wrapper.upload_documents(documents)

    # To get the upload file arg here, you'll need to either mock the partial call here, 
    # or actually call it and get the return value
    mock_pool_instance.starmap.assert_called_once_with_args(upload_file, documents)
```

Then you'd want to take your existing logic and test your upload_document function separately:

```
@patch.object(Session, 'post')
def test_upload_file(self, post_mock):
    response_mock = Mock()
    post_mock.return_value = response_mock
    response_mock.ok = True

    with Wrapper() as wrapper:
        wrapper.upload_document(document)

    mc = post_mock.mock_calls
```

This gives you coverage both on your function that's creating and controlling your pool, and the function that's being called by the pool instance. Caveat this with I didn't test this, but am leaving some of it for you to fill in the blanks since it looks like it's an abbreviated version of the actual module in your original question.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
def test_study_upload(self):
    def call_direct(func_var, documents):
        return func_var(documents)

    with patch('yourmodule.Pool.starmap', new=call_direct)
        with Wrapper() as wrapper:
            wrapper.upload_documents(documents)
```

This is patching out the starmap call so that it calls the function you pass in directly. It circumvents the Pool entirely; the bottom line being that you can't really dive into those subprocesses created by multiprocessing.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's the only way. Loosing integration test makes me sad however.

Comment: I look at it more like: if you're testing the function that is being handled by your Pool already, and you're testing the function that's handling adding tasks to the Pool, you're fully covered! There might be another way around it by patching _just_ the starmap. I'll edit my question with a suggestion. @amorfis